# Linux asynchronous epoll() server having problems when EPOLLRDHUP occurrs

Tags: c, linux, sockets, asynchronous, epoll

I'm trying to make an asynchronous web server using epoll() in Linux, but problems occur whenever the event EPOLLRDHUP occurs. When the flag EPOLLONESHOT is not set, the server tries to process a useless event (not EPOLLIN or EPOLLOUT) multiple times during the loop without stopping, which causes the server to be come completely unresponsive (and require a restart). When the flag EPOLLONESHOT is set, the server simply becomes unresponsive for a short period of time (seconds) and then becomes responsive again (which still is not ideal). I'm unsure what could be causing this, since I close the socket whenever EPOLLRDHUP occurs. Here is my code:

```
int server_fd, new_socket; 
long valRead;
struct sockaddr_in address;
int addrlen = sizeof(address);

//setup code (bind(), etc.) would be here

struct connection {
    int socket;
    unsigned int connectionType;
    void* dataToSend;
    unsigned int dataByteSize;
    struct epoll_event event;
    bool active;
};

struct connection* connections = (struct connection*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(struct connection));
connections[0].socket = server_fd;
connections[0].connectionType = 1U;
connections[0].event.events = EPOLLIN;
connections[0].event.data.ptr = &connections[0];

unsigned int connectionIndex = 1U;

fcntl(server_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

int epollFd = epoll_create(10);
epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, server_fd, &connections[0].event);

struct epoll_event* receivedEvents = malloc(sizeof(struct epoll_event) * 1000);
struct connection currentConnection;

#define MAX_EVENTS 10
int numEventsReady;
unsigned int eventIndex;
while (1) {
    printText("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n", 46);

    numEventsReady = epoll_wait(epollFd, receivedEvents, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
    if (numEventsReady == -1) {
        printf("\nErrno:");
        printf("%i", errno);
        printf("\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "epoll_wait() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(7);
    }
    eventIndex = 0U;
    while (eventIndex < numEventsReady) {
        currentConnection = *((struct connection*)receivedEvents[eventIndex].data.ptr);
        switch (currentConnection.connectionType) {
        case 1U:
            //printText("\nConnected", 10);
            new_socket = accept4(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen, SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC);
            if (new_socket != -1) {
                connections[connectionIndex].socket = new_socket;
                connections[connectionIndex].connectionType = 2U;
                connections[connectionIndex].event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP;
                connections[connectionIndex].event.data.ptr = &connections[connectionIndex];

                epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, new_socket, &connections[connectionIndex].event);

                ++connectionIndex;
            }
            break;
        case 2U:
            if (receivedEvents[eventIndex].events & EPOLLERR) {
                printf("\nEPOLLERR\n");
                close(currentConnection.socket);
            }
            else if(receivedEvents[eventIndex].events & EPOLLHUP) {
                printf("\nEPOLLHUP\n");
                close(currentConnection.socket);
            }
            else if(receivedEvents[eventIndex].events & EPOLLRDHUP) {
                printf("\nEPOLLRDHUP\n");
                close(currentConnection.socket);
            }
            else if (receivedEvents[eventIndex].events & EPOLLIN) {
                valRead = recv(currentConnection.socket, buffer, 65536, 0);
                if (valRead < 1) {
                    printf("recv error");
                    if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                        printf("errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK");
                        close(currentConnection.socket);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                printText(buffer, valRead);

                currentConnection.event.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLRDHUP;
                currentConnection.event.data.ptr = &currentConnection;
                epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, currentConnection.socket, &currentConnection.event);

                if (buffer[0] == 'G' && buffer[1] == 'E' && buffer[2] == 'T') {
                    switch (buffer[5]) {
                    case ' ': //default web page (index.htm)
                        currentConnection.dataToSend = indexHtm;
                        currentConnection.dataByteSize = sizeof(indexHtm);
                        //sendSocketData(new_socket, indexHtm, sizeof(indexHtm));
                        break;
                    }
               }
              else if (receivedEvents[eventIndex].events & EPOLLOUT) {
                valRead = send(currentConnection.socket, currentConnection.dataToSend, currentConnection.dataByteSize, 0);
                if (valRead == -1) {
                    printf("send error has ocurred\n");
                    if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                        printf("\nerrno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK\n");
                        close(currentConnection.socket);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                currentConnection.event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP;
                currentConnection.event.data.ptr = &currentConnection;
                valRead = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, currentConnection.socket, &currentConnection.event);
            }
            break;
        }
        ++eventIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code example is a little too involved. Can you cut down the code to just the wait loop and the close of socket and the recipe to create the loop?

Comment: What is `MAX_EVENTS`?

Comment: @jxh 10, it is passed into the maxevents parameter of epoll_wait()

Comment: [https://tio.run/##jVJdb4IwFH33V9y5zJSIDnzdNCHqMjMmRvHJEUKgzmYMCC0a4/ztrlAV0EnWB7if555zW7f16bqHexK4fuJheKZb@si2EabtVa9WDtPQ/cLsOo6j0PfL4SQglHkXpcwjYTnkUIrjFPFAAgbfDgkArUPiSbCrAT9plEaLjvV0doPcJNAFRbiUxYnLIGNi4zXmWazy9A7amUe5PZwYuj4a/2R/Y24KYzp4nU@EOTRhfxuuUwX3b5ScfcwxxEYjh8RIe7F1o6/pMsyM/ps9M6dD7V0GReYLkESX2BaK4a4LLVXKofDS42Bijhtjh2GklnvSimJXnNczP83KQo/dN3VbGwzSqQvFkqGB1arpmxXxMSAUnPE2DmECsIFlULkCSYIe/x6vNOO8BIRPm2zA6UKKJemJYi5uieoPHoQJ@wjqMpDj3NNx/ZBixLmq1kXmprp3o6iuU2jbVxIcjSv4keCKXjVa9mAqAFdJVC1Ysf6c1WwSEd7X9ofDLw Try it online!]

Comment: Above is an attempt to reproduce your problem, but there is no infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern here, which you use twice, is wrong:

```
currentConnection.event.data.ptr = &currentConnection;
valRead = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 
                    currentConnection.socket, &currentConnection.event);
```

You are setting the `data.ptr` to your local variable `currentConnection` (which is reused and overwritten all the time), when it really should point into your connections-array!

As far as I can see it, `currentConnection` should be a pointer type:

```
struct connection *currentConnection;
```

and the assignment later in your code should be like

```
currentConnection = (struct connection*)receivedEvents[eventIndex].data.ptr;
```

You have to fix the struct member accesses of course and the setting of `data.ptr` like you do here:

```
currentConnection.event.data.ptr = &currentConnection;
```

shouldn't be necessary at all.

Comment: I think you have identified a root cause, but the minimal fix is to remove the `currentConnection.event.data.ptr = &currentConnection;` statement.